# Is it possible to make a FAT32 partition where the start of the cluster data will align with the cluster size?

Tags: partition, fat32

What I'm getting at is that I've tried to make a bunch of fat32 partitions of various sizes so that the reserved space plus the 2 copies of the fat table would land me at a byte position that was evenly divisible by the cluster size.
I've tried small and large, and I can never get it to line up. With a 4k cluster size I'm either 1 sector over or 3 under, and with larger cluster sizes, it's always off by more than that, but it never exactly lines up.

So I'm wondering if it's a known thing that it's not possible?

Comment: Not a real hint here, but can you tell the tool you're using? Maybe (I guess) there exist other that give you finer control.

Comment: I'm creating these partitions on linux, so I'm using mkfs.vfat. Actually I'm using gparted, and I'm sure it's using mkfs.vfat under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally just delete the question, but I figure this could be useful for somebody else needing this information.
I finally found one.

If you make a FAT32 partition of 2100 megs in size, it will have a 4k cluster size and the start of the cluster data will land at 4308992 which is evenly divisible by the 4096 cluster size.